# How to manage several Serial messages in processing

Tags: io, arduino, processing, message

I am reading the UID of my RFID card and storing it in a variable called `myUID`.

After that I am authorizing to the card with the factory key and read block number 4 (which has been written to earlier) and store it in a string `readBlock`.

On the Arduino, I print out the variables onto the serial interface like so.

```
Serial.println(myUID);
Serial.println(readBlock);
```

On the client side, I use a Java program that reads in serial data. My program uses the [Processing Library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html).

```
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;

void setup() {
 output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
 mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
 mySerial.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw(){
  while (mySerial.available() > 0) {
  String inBuffer = mySerial.readString();   
  if (inBuffer != null)
    output.println(inBuffer); 
  }
}
void keyPressed() { // Press a key to save the data
  output.flush(); // Write the remaining data
  output.close(); // Finish the file
  exit(); // Stop the program
}
```

Now my data.txt is expected to look like

```
xxx xxx xxx xxx (uid of card)
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... (read block from card)
```

but looks like

```
237 63 58 1
07
37 37 95
 37 
97 98 50 54 37 5
4 55 102 55 52 
45 98
```

I have tried several things like `readStringUntil('\n');` in the Processing Library but without success.

Comment: Okay, so I managed to get the append function working, but the text is still weirdly formatted... I do not know why :(

Comment: Have you confirmed that the baud rate of  `9600` is correct? Also is the `RFID` card returning characters encoded in ASCII or just binary data?

Comment: I have confirmed the baud rate and the card is returning hex data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone interested, I have fixed the problem myself with many hours of searching Google, so maybe this will help someone in the future:

I could fix it with this code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
int count = 0;
String input = "";
String fileName = dataPath("SET FILEPATH HERE");

Serial mySerial;

import java.io.*;

void setup() {
  mySerial = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  mySerial.bufferUntil('\n');

  File f = new File(fileName);
  if (f.exists()) {
    f.delete();
  }
}

void draw(){}

// listen to serial events happening
void serialEvent(Serial mySerial){
  input = mySerial.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  write(input, count);
  count++;
}

// function for writing the data to the file
void write(String inputString, int counter) {
  // should new data be appended or replace any old text in the file?  
  boolean append = false;

  // just for my purpose, because I have got two lines of serial which need to get written to the file 
  //(Line 1: UID of card, Line 2: Read block of card)  
  if(counter < 2){
    append = true;  
  }
  else{
    count = 0;
  }


  try {
    File file = new File("D:/xampp/htdocs/pizza/src/rfid/data.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, append);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

    pw.write(inputString + '\n');
    pw.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Exception ");
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```